# Streaming file upload to a rest file server using node js without temporary files

Tags: node.js, express

```
fileupload = (req, res, uploadEndpoint) ->
  req.connection.setTimeout 10000
  poster = request.post(uploadEndpoint, (err, response, body) ->
    console.log err + ":" + response.statusCode + ":" + body
    jsonbody = JSON.parse(body)
    console.log "jsonbody: " + JSON.stringify(jsonbody)
    console.log "Error ofcourse"  if jsonbody.error isnt `undefined`
  )
  req.pipe(poster).pipe res
```

This is acoffee-script snippet. Im using it for uploading a file into another rest based fileserver. This is not working when the file is big. this gives me this error. Expressjs is used without `bodyparser` but `app.use express.json() app.use express.urlencoded()` these two are used. I dont want o use temp files to avoid expensive i/o in between. Looks like it is piping issue. Any insight?

```
{"error":"multipart: Part Read: read tcp 192.168.1.1:49688: i/o timeout"}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a middleware I wrote for doing this very job (including handling zipped files!).  It uses [multiparty](https://github.com/superjoe30/node-multiparty), so you'll have to `npm install` that if you want to use it.

```
multiparty  = require("multiparty")
zlib        = require("zlib")

stream_file_upload = (req, res, next) ->
# Create the formidable form
form = new multiparty.Form()
needed_parts = 0 
succeeded_parts = 0 

form.on "part", (part) ->
    needed_parts += 1

    if part.filename
        # Handle unzipping
        unzipper = null

        if /\.zip$/.exec(part.filename)
            unzipper = zlib.createUnzip()
        else if /\.gz$/.exec(part.filename)
            unzipper = zlib.createGunzip()

        if unzipper
            part.pipe(unzipper)

        req.file = unzipper or part
        next() if needed_parts == succeeded_parts += 1

    else
        # Need to wait for these to get parsed before next
        val = ""
        part.on "data", (data) ->
            val += data
        part.on "end", () ->
            req.body[part.name] = val 
            next() if needed_parts == succeeded_parts += 1

form.parse req
```

The middleware adds a `req.file` variable which is a stream.

Comment: Thanks but it behaves same as the original `req.pipe(request).pipe res`. No difference in behavior. It looks like the problem is with piping speed between input and output stream. As when the rest-based file server and the nodeJS UI server is in the same network it works with 4.5 MB file. But when these two servers are in different networks then only smaller files work. Now I have not tested rigorously with all the file sizes to get the limit but I tested with less than 1 MB file that works in both the situations and 4.5 MB files works if both the servers are in same network.